# Owl Carousel 2 - hide custom nav (if 1 item)

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, hide, owl-carousel-2

I'm looking for a way to hide the Owl Carousel custom navigation, and to stop the "loop" functionality if there is only one item.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
});

owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
$(".prev").click(function () {
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});
$(".next").click(function () {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Schakelen/agbsoh2e/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first of all, use an if

```
loop: $('.owl-carousel img').length > 1 ? true : false,
```

This will measure the amount of `img`s in the carousel, and disable the loop. We can also add an if to use the `hide()` function

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agbsoh2e/9/)